# how to fetch all customers in spring and hibernate using session

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

This is my `CustomerDao` class,
there are two methods one is `save()`(its working well) and `allCustomer()`(this is not working).

I want to fetch all the customers

```
@Repository
public class CustomerDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Serializable save(Customer customer) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(customer);
    }

    public ArrayList allCustomer() {
        System.out.println("dnbf8uds");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        System.out.println("dnbf8uds");
        org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery("from Customer");

        List<Customer> customers = query.list();

        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

        for (Customer c : customers) {
            System.out.println(c);
            list.add(c);
        }
        return list;
    }       
}
```

**this is the error**

I created a main java class to check the methods:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at app.dao.CustomerDao.allCustomer(CustomerDao.java:37)
    at test.test.main(test.java:24)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: what is line 37 in your class that you have listed here? on that line something that you are dot accessing is not instantiated properly.

Comment: I suspect the main contender is this line: session.createQuery("from Customer"); Why are you creating a new session here: sessionFactory.openSession(); instead of using the current session like you do in the save method: sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().

Comment: Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

Comment: try sessingFactory.getCurrentSession() instead of opening a new Session as @Margaret mentioned.

Comment: @SuhadMendis that means sessionFactory is not getting autowired. That's why it is getting initialized as null. Check the spring configuration for sessionFactory or post your spring configuration here.

Comment: Criteria criteria  = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Customer.class);     i use this but is also the same

Comment: post also your class `test.java`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your `test.java` class is not `Spring` maintained, so the injection of `CustomerDao` does not work. Even if you initialize the dao in it with

```
CustomerDao dao = new CustomerDao();
```

you are out of Spring context too, you can't instantiate it with the `new` keyword, it must be injected by Spring, that's why your `sessionFactory` is null.